# User deleted from domain, cannot login. What is the right way to revert?

Tags: windows-server-2012

```
                         MCSE
                     ==============
```

I delete user from domain now user can't login with domain or with local user. What i can do now please help me.

Comment: More detail should be included so edit your question and specify the EXACT message you get when you try to login locally, the exact message you get when you try to login with a domain account, and the exact steps you took when you deleted this account (i.e. how you deleted the profile on the Windows Server 2012 server, how you deleted the AD account, etc.)? A local user account signing onto a PC and a domain user account signing on a PC joined to a domain are not the same. Very confusing content in your question at the moment.

Comment: -1 very bad title

Comment: More information.  What version of Windows?  Did you recreate the user account?  Did you mean computer account?  Can you login with another local account?  Can you login with another AD account?  As well as @JUICED_IT request.  Welcome to the site.  Cheers!

Comment: Don't be hard on this guy. :) Looks like there's a really good answer below. You can reverse your vote. :) Have a great day!

Comment: Additionally you may be able to just restore the AD object using the Microsoft methods... Here's some starting point articles: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd379509(v=ws.10).aspx and https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978013.aspx

Answer (score 4):

You can do the following things.

**Recreate the user in Active Directory. The user will have no profile and files are gone, but he can login again.**

If you need to rescue the files, go to the computer, unplug the network cable and try logging in again with the username and password.

It should work now as it logs in from cache. Without plugging in the network cable, check the settings so you can recreate them later.

Recreate the profile in Active Directory, and configure it.